# Race condition between commandLink and actionFunction

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

There appears to be a race condition between my commandLink and actionFunction within one form. The `commandLink` calls a js function validate() that calls the  actionFunction `saveCustomRoles` which saves something to a custom_roles String in the controller and then calls the apex controller's `back()` function that redirects the view to another page. However, it always takes about 2-10 clicks on the button before I actually get redirected back.

visualforce:

```
    <apex:form>
      <apex:commandLink styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onClick="validate();">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--left">
          <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.lightning, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#back')}"></use>
        </svg>
        Back
      </apex:commandLink>
      <apex:actionFunction name="saveCustomRoles" action="{!back}" reRender="">
         <apex:param name="saveCustomRoles" value="" assignTo="{!custom_roles}"/>
      </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
```

js:

```
function validate() {
  saveCustomRoles(customRoleCart.toString());
}
```

apex:

```
public String custom_roles {get;set;}

public PageReference back() {
    PageReference pr = Page.HomePage;
    pr.getparameters().put('custom_roles',custom_roles);    
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<apex:commandLink>` will cause a form post to take place. This post happens immediately after your `onclick` javascript function finishes. Your `actionFunction` also causes a form post. Essentially, you're double-posting the form (depending on how quickly these two behaviors happen).

You need to prevent the commandlink's form post from taking place because instead you are wanting the form post to happen when you call the `<apex:actionFunction>`. The commandLink's post happens because Salesforce appends its script after your own `onclick` function when rendered.

Changing the `onclick` of your `commandLink` to prevent the default action should do the trick. This will cause the browser to return control to the page rather than continuing to execute the SFDC appended JS.

`onClick="validate(); return false;"`

Comment: Excellent. I never knew the importance of return false but I was always using :)

Answer (score 0):

There is some latency involved when you work with Actions Functions. You can use the status tag to validate the same.

```
<apex:actionStatus id="processingStatus" stopText="" >
    <apex:facet name="start">
        <div>
            <div class="popupBackground" />
            <img src="/img/loading.gif"/>

        </div>
    </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>
```

and update your action function like this

```
<apex:actionFunction status="processingStatus" name="saveCustomRoles" action="{!back}" reRender="">
```

Also, if you are just redirecting the page using this method, we can consider js to do that as well. Just update your validation function as

```
function validate() {
    //To encode the values to URL Format
    var customRoles = encodeURIComponent(customRoleCart.toString());
    window.location.href = '{!URLFOR($Page.HomePage)}?custom_roles='+customRoles;

}
```